# Memory and pointers in a BST

Tags: java, search, binary-search-tree

In a binary search tree that takes a simple object.....when creating the getter and setter methods for the left, right, and parent.  There are concerns about what is happening when a parent node is set. Code bellow...

The code:

```
 public void setParent(Person parent) {
  parent = new Person( parent.getName(), parent.getWeight());
```

The example code that inspired the code:

```
 public void setParent(Node parent) {
  this.parent = parent;
 }
```

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear.  Which programming language? Are you asking if you're allowed to return a null when left/right/parent nodes are requested?

Comment: Is this homework?  Why do your nodes need to know who their parents are?  That just makes it a mess to keep track of.

Comment: If you do not track who is your parent how can you build a tree ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating what is essentially a clone of the parent object.  This is different from just saving the pointer to the parent object.

Obviously, you'll be taking more memory space by duplicating the parent object.  More importantly, you're not duplicating the parent's references.  So if you try to traverse the tree, go to a node's parent, then try to visit its other children, you draw a bunch of null pointers.

The `this.parent` is a reference to the current object's `parent` pointer.

It doesn't actually mean that `this` is a parent.  In fact, `this.parent` is used to distinguish the local `parent` pointer from the incoming parameter `parent`.

```
class Person{
    Person parent; // <---- this is the "this.parent" attribute, and is initially undefined
    public void setParent(Person parent){ // <---- the "Person parent" on this line is an incoming parameter
        this.parent = parent; //<---- "this.parent" refers to the attribute, and "parent" refers to the parameter
    }
}
```